# Change the character separating username and hostname in the terminal

Tags: command-line

I would like to replace the `@` character separating my username and hostname in the terminal.

[image: My current username and hostname]

As an example `pietro@camelot` -> `pietroⒶcamelot`

I can't find proper info on how to do it, except that i should probably edit my `.bashrc` file. Attempts to change it have failed to show any difference though.

Can anyone tell me if there's a proper way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use different tools like: http://ezprompt.net to create your desired prompt, what you want can be achieved by:

```
export PS1="\uⒶ\h\w\\$ "
```

Put it in your `.bashrc` and you are done.

- `\u` : user
- `Ⓐ`  : exactly a `Ⓐ` char.
- `\h` : hostname
- `\w` : working directory
- `\\$` : prompt sign